# How to get text response from http client delete method in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am getting an error in my code.What i want is  text response from server but when i wrote below code it is throwing  run time error.

Code :

```
 public deleteChapterTopic(deleteUserId, clientId: number, grade: string, subjectId: number, chapterTopicId: number, parentChapterTopicId: number, chapterOrTopic: number) {
    let options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: {
        deleteUserId: deleteUserId,
        chapterId: chapterTopicId,
        subjectId: subjectId,
        grade: grade,
        parentChapterTopicId: parentChapterTopicId,
        clientId: clientId,
        chapterOrTopic: chapterOrTopic
      },
      observe: "body",
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',

    };
 
    return this.http.delete(BackendService.CHAPTER_TOPIC, options);
  }
```

Error:

```
   ERROR in src/app/backend/backend.service.ts:581:59 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      The last overload gave the following error.
        Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; body: { deleteUserId: number; chapterId: number; subjectId: number; grade: string; parentChapterTopicId: number; clientId: number; chapterOrTopic: number; }; observe: string; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { 
[header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
          Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

    581     return this.http.delete(BackendService.CHAPTER_TOPIC, options);
```

How do i solve this problem so that i can send data in payload and get response in text both.
Thanks in advance.
~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

What is "body"? it should be params.

```js
public deleteChapterTopic(deleteUserId, clientId: number, grade: string, subjectId: number, chapterTopicId: number, parentChapterTopicId: number, chapterOrTopic: number) {
    let options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      params: {
        deleteUserId: deleteUserId,
        chapterId: chapterTopicId,
        subjectId: subjectId,
        grade: grade,
        parentChapterTopicId: parentChapterTopicId,
        clientId: clientId,
        chapterOrTopic: chapterOrTopic
      },
      observe: "body",
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',

    };
 
    return this.http.delete(BackendService.CHAPTER_TOPIC, options);
  }
```

Comment: getting error error TS2769: No overload matches this call.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates, that you want to add a body to your HTTP DELETE request. The HTTP 1.1 specification (RFC 7231) explicitly permits an entity body in a DELETE request.

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

Hence with Angular HTTTP Client it is not possible to add a body to a DELETE request.

You can, however, include Query Parameters in your request, which are defined by the `params` property. In your case just rename `body` within `options` to `params`.

Comment: I want a favour from u